# Arduino Yun Accept Captive Portal

Tags: arduino, wifi, portal

I have an Arduino Yun, and I would like to have it connect to a particular WiFi hotspot.  This particular hotspot has a captive portal and I want to have the Yun, process the "Accept" button that comes up on the web page after connecting to the hotspot.  What code would be required for this?  I understand I'll have to get the details of the particular captive portal, but i'm looking for the basic rough code to do this.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "captive portal" (specific product?), but any button on a website will send back a URL to the server. My guess: Analyze the webpage (i.e., the button onClick code) to see what it sends, and make the Arduino send that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perharps could use an headless browser tool like phantomjs launched by a nodejs app. Then you can simulate the navigation on the portal and input user / password